# I need a regex to match all single words and every pair of two words

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Im using PHP preg_match_all function and I need it to return an array of every single word AND every pair of words, including those single words, for example:

```
preg_match_all('/the regex/','Stackoverflow is awesome',$matches);
```

The $matches array should contain:

('Stackoverflow' , 'is' , 'awesome' , 'Stackoverflow is' , 'is awesome')

I've tried with this regex but not getting the expected results:

[a-z]+\s?[a-z]*

Comment: I think you don't look for a regex, this seems to be similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3200272/3933332 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve that with just regular expressions. I would say, use explode and construct the array yourself.

```
$string = 'Stackoverflow is awesome';
$parts = explode(' ', $string);
for ($i = 1; $i < count($parts); $i++) {
    $parts[] = $parts[$i - 1] . ' ' . $parts[$i];
}
```

Comment: I ended up using your answer, but instead of explode I use `preg_split("/[\s,.]+/", $string)` function because I am dealing with natural text (with commas, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `\S+` to match all the words. And next you do `\S+\s+\S+`, it won't match the previously matched characters because regex by default won't do overlapping matches. In-order to make the regex engine to do overlapping matches, you need to put the pattern which matches two words at a time inside a capturing group and also place the capturing group inside positive lookarounds.

```
$s = "Stackoverflow is awesome";
$regex = '~(?=(\S+\s+\S+))|\S+~';
preg_match_all($regex, $s, $matches);
$matches = array_values(array_filter(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $matches)));
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Stackoverflow
    [1] => is
    [2] => awesome
    [3] => Stackoverflow is
    [4] => is awesome
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives limits the phrasing to two words.

```
<?php
$str = "Stackoverflow is awesome";
$words = explode(" ",$str);
$num_words = count($words);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_words; $i++) {
  for ($j = $i; $j < $num_words; $j++) {
    $num = 0;

    $temp = "";
    for ($k = $i; $k <= $j; $k++) { 
       $num++;
       $temp .= $words[$k] . " ";             
    }

    if($num < 3)
    echo $temp . "<br />";
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple regex

> ```
>  /\w+/i
> ```

Rewrite:

```
     preg_match_all('/\w+/i','Stackoverflow is awesome',$matches);
 print_r($matches);
```

See this in action **[here](https://eval.in/300840)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookaheads here:

```
preg_match_all('/(?=(\b(\w+)(?:\s+(\w+)\b|$)))/','Stackoverflow is awesome',$matches);
```

Now double words:

```
print_r($matches[1]);
Array
(
    [0] => Stackoverflow is
    [1] => is awesome
    [2] => awesome
)
```

And single words:

```
print_r($matches[2]);
Array
(
    [0] => Stackoverflow
    [1] => is
    [2] => awesome
)
```

**PS:** `awesome` prints in double words also because it is the last word.