# Create groups of values from array values

Tags: php, arrays

I will do my best to explain this idea to you. I have an array of values, i would like to know if there is a way to create another array of combined values. So, for example:

If i have this code:

`array('ec','mp','ba');`

I would like to be able to output something like this:

`'ec,mp', 'ec,ba', 'mp,ba', 'ec,mp,ba'`

Is this possible? Ideally i don't want to have duplicate entries like `'ec,mp'` and `'mp,ec'` though, as they would be the same thing

Comment: Have you tried something (code;research;pseudo code) ?

Comment: Is this the same as what you need?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572546/php-merge-arrays-with-only-not-duplicated-values

Comment: @Rizier123 i havent tried anything because i don't know where to start with this logic if i'm honest

Comment: @johnny no because that's merging 2 different arrays into one, i'd like to use this one array and create a new one with paired values

Comment: It's not entirely what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3200283/3933332 But I hope it gives you some ideas :)

Comment: what is the exact output that you're looking for? do you want all the couples? Or all the subsets with cardinality bigger than one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085019/creating-all-combination-in-php

Comment: @marcosh i've already shown the desired output in the question

Comment: @AndyHolmes I was asking for a clarification, since it's not clear to me what needs to happen if, for example, the starting array has 4 elements and not 3

Comment: You want the power set http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092781/finding-the-subsets-of-an-array-in-php

Comment: @CrayonViolent power set is exactly it! thank you

Comment: @CrayonViolent That was a good one.  Good question too.  https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/power-set.html

Answer (score 1):

You can take an arbitrary decision to always put the "lower" string first. Once you made this decision, it's just a straight-up nested loop:

```
$arr = array('ec','mp','ba');
$result = array();
foreach ($arr as $s1) {
    foreach ($arr as $s2) {
        if ($s1 < $s2) {
            $result[] = array($s1, $s2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, only thing it doesn't do is out put all array values into one combination (`'ec,mp,ba'`) but i can work on that. Thank you for a quick solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
$arr = array('ec','mp','ba', 'ds', 'sd', 'ad');

$newArr = array();

foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {
        if($key % 2 == 0) {
                $newArr[] = $val;
        } else {
                $newArr[floor($key/2)] = $newArr[floor($key/2)] . ',' . $val;
        }
}

print_r($newArr);
```

And the result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ec,mp
    [1] => ba,ds
    [2] => sd,ad
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the function [implode](http://php.net/implode)

```
<?php

    $array = array('ec','mp','ba');
    $comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

    echo $comma_separated; // ec,mp,ba
?>
```

You could use this as a base for your program and what you are trying to achieve.